# Upload file as octet stream from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a file located in the Blob Storage (simple .txt file) and I want to upload this file via HTTP PUT methods with a application/octet-stream content type to one of my web services. I am using Azure Data Factory v2 for this purpose. I have tried to use Copy Data activity, however:

- I am not able to use HTTP connector as a sink
- I am only able to use REST connector as a sink, but it seems that the file is uploaded as a json, not a octet stream.

Is it possible to use one of those connectors in order to upload the file?
Should I use another connector? Or should I use another resource like Azure Function, because I am not able to do it using ADF?

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct REST as sink only support content type : Json
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#rest-as-sink

"REST connector as sink works with the REST APIs that accept JSON. "